# Python itertools create iterator of random subset

Tags: python, random, iterator, python-itertools

I have an iterator `itertools.combinations(big_matrix,50)` with `big_matrix.shape = (65,x)`, so there are about 10^14 combinations. I want to get a random subset of say 10000 of this combinations, also as an iterator, to save memory.

I tried the itertools recipe

```
def random_combination(iterable, r):
  "Random selection from itertools.combinations(iterable, r)"
  pool = tuple(iterable)
  n = len(pool)
  indices = sorted(random.sample(xrange(n), r))
  return tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
```

but `tuple(iterable)` creates a tuple of the 10^14 values, and the function does not return an iterator but an array.

`random.sample` does not work, because it is unable to get the number of elements in the `itertools.combinations` object.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just produce random combinations, tracking what you've seen before:

```
def random_combinations(matrix, size):
    seen = set()
    n = len(matrix)
    while True:
        new_sample = tuple(sorted(random.sample(xrange(n), size)))
        if new_sample not in seen:
            seen.add(new_sample)
            yield tuple(matrix[i] for i in new_sample)
```

Iterating through all possible combinations to sample is not efficient, you still end up testing all 10^14 combinations.

The above generator picks a random combination each time you iterate; if you need a certain number, use a loop or `itertools.islice()`; picking 10 random combinations would be:

```
combinations_sample = list(islice(random_combinations(matrix, 50), 10))
```

You may have misunderstood what the function you found *does*; it does much the same as my function above but produces just the one random combination, without tracking what was produced before. You were supposed to use it on `matrix`, not on all combinations of `matrix`.

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing exactly. Are you creating the combinations yourself? I don't see the `itertools.combinations` anywhere.

Comment: @user3696412 yes, this creates random combinations rather than all then selecting from those.